# Video output within Tkinter?

Tags: python, video, tkinter

I posted a similar question a while ago but haven't received any answers so i thought i might ask a more generic question:

Does anyone know how to, through any means, output true video, not a rapidly changing sequence of images, in a Tkinter window with python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need an extension like TkVideo or Quicktime to do that, not sure there is a python style wrapper for it available yet.
https://github.com/patthoyts/tkvideo

Comment: The link asks for username and password!

Comment: Seems the old link is dead by now. There is a copy of the 2014 state at https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkvideo.berlios/ the new site of the author is on github, as linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Python tkinter can now *play videos* within the UI *with sound*,check this module:[tkintervideo](https://github.com/cool-dev-guy/tkintervideo).
This is done with the help of many modules,so it now supports seeking and forwarding/back-warding options.
[image]

```py
from tkintervideo import player
from tkintervideo.tools import Controls
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk
import time

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        sv_ttk.set_theme('dark')
        self.m_widget = player.Player(self,height=200,width=300)

        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1,weight=0)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.m_widget.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=tk.NSEW,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.m_widget.load('output.avi')

        self.controls = Controls(self,self.m_widget)
        self.m_widget.bind("<<Duration>>",self.controls.update_scale)
        self.controls.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=tk.NSEW,padx=10,pady=10)
myApp = App()
myApp.mainloop()
```

If any errors occur add it to the github issues of the project.