# Is It Possible to Embed a Video In a Tkinter Window?

Tags: python, video, tkinter, embed

I am working on python program with the Tkinter GUI. For one part of the program I would like to display a video in the Tkinter window, is this possible? If yes how is it done? I don't care about what file format is needed.

Comment: See here, this seems to be a common question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362613/video-output-within-tkinter